# java applet - array checking

Tags: java, arrays, applet, tile

OK so my code is here: http://www.so.pastebin.com/m7V8rQ2n

What I want to know... let's say I have an image which I can redraw on tiles... is there a way to check for future tiles so I DON'T go out of bounds of my already defined tile map?

Like if I were at the edge of a map... it would NOT let me go past it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough info. Tell us more what's going on and what you want done. Be descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, preventing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` can be done by simply making sure that the index is within the bound.

> #### [JLS 10.4 Array Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.4)
>
> All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length `n` can be indexed by the integers `0` to `n-1`.

Thus, a simple check like this is quite typical:

```
if (i >= 0 && i < arr.length) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Barring nasty things like `arr` getting reassigned between the check and the access, the above code will *NEVER* throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

#### 2D array "boards"

Often, you can be a lot more specific, e.g. when you have rectangular "boards" stored in a two-dimensional array (or rather, array of arrays in Java).

```
final int M = 10;  // height, i.e. number of rows
final int N = 8;   // width, i.e. number of columns
final int[][] board = new int[M][N];
```

Then you can have a method like the following:

```
boolean isInBound(int r, int c) {
    return (r >= 0) && (r < M) && (c >= 0) && (c < N);
}
```

The bound check is both easier to read and to write, since we know that we have an *MxN* board. If `isInBound(r, c)`, then `board[r][c]` will *NEVER* throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.